# Triple integrals - spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Integrate the function:

$$f(x,y,z)=1/\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$

over the region $R$ which is the set of all points outside the sphere $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1$ but inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$.

I am pretty sure that spherical coordinates are the way to go because I realized that they make the intergrand equal to 0. However I am unsure of my limits of integration. I tried the following:

$\theta$ limits of integration: 0 to 2$\pi$,

$\phi$ limits of integration: 0 to $\pi$,

$\rho$ limits of integration: 2cos$\phi$ to 2,

My result was $4\pi^2$.

Comment: I suggest that you write the integral as a difference of two, one over the bigger ball, and one over the smaller. In the bigger, spherical coordinates work fine, in the smaller, use shifted spherical coordinates (a shift by 1 in the z coordinate). I get $4\pi^2-4\pi$ as a result. Please try this and clarify the question if you need further help.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will try asap